# Can't connect to MSSQL Server 2000 with "IP Address" but works with server "hostname"

Tags: networking, sql-server, security, authentication

this happens after applying the SP3 on MSSQL Server 2000, I just can connect with SA login or DOMAIN\Administrators (built in) users, How can I reenable the Integrated Security connection?

Hey Hey... I discover that the server now just accepts connections for "SISTEM" not more for 192.168.0.3 (private ip for the MMSQL Server), so Why this things happen? I was searching in the Service Pack documentation and never advice for this, so the big problem is that all the applications in connection string are like "Server=192.168.0.3;Initial Catalog='dbblabla'..."

any way to achieve this?

We have subnets so the server "SISTEM" resolves 192.168.0.3 and 172.16.104.180

I recently patch to SPIV

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your client's Programs / SQL Server start menu, look for

```
SQL Server Client configuration
```

and see if TCP/IP is an active protocol in the configuration.

Another (not probable, but theoretically possible) think you could check: does your server have multiple IP addresses associated to the network interface(s)? Maybe the name "SISTEM" resolves to a different IP addres. Try

```
nslookup sistem
```

and see if 192.168.0.3 is returned as IP address.

*Note:* The current service pack for SQL Server 2000 is **Service Pack 4**, released in 2005. I strongly suggest using that service pack version, because it addreses some security issues.

Comment: yes we have 3 subnets

Comment: prompt find 192.168.0.3 and 172.16.104.180, also in the first lines tells something that DNS request time out, time out was 2 seconds, cant find the servername for the ip 192.168.0.3 Timed out

Comment: is there a difference in "ping 192.168.0.3" and "ping sistem"?

Comment: yes when I ping 192.168.0.3 it works normally, but when I ping SISTEM it takes like 6 seconds to start ping normally

Comment: if you do a "ping sistem" which ip address is shown?

Comment: the same but takes more than 5 seconds to start :S

Comment: There's definely a DNS issue which needs dealing with.  Doesn't explain SQL not responding to the IP, but responding to he name.  Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you are connecting to the SQL Server via TCP?  If you are it doesn't care what name you use to connect.  If you try to connect, to the port and the port is listening it will respond.

What's the exact error that your users are getting?

And why are you just now installing SQL 2000 SP3?

Comment: I can connect using the hostname example : "MSSQL-SERV01" but I cant not do it with it private ip 192.168.0.3

Comment: What's the exact error that you get when using the IP?